# C++ - Loading Base64 Encoded String of an image to Boost GIL image/view

Tags: c++, boost-gil

I'm using Boosts Generic Image Library. I'm being given a string representation of an image. After decoding it, could I directly make an Image or View object with that data? Or would I need to write the data to the computer as example.png and use GIL's read_image functions? The documentation mentions dynamic images but still takes a filename as a parameter to the i/o functions.

I would ideally be looking for a function that takes a string or byte array as a parameter rather than the image name to be loaded from disk. Something like GDI+ FromStream.  I see that the documentation says "All functions take the filename or a device as the first parameter. A device could be a FILE*, std::ifstream, and TIFF*." Maybe it is possible to edit the contents of an ifstream to have the image data, not sure if this is actually possible though.

Comment: welcome Stone :) You might consider putting some sample code in your question. You can wrap sample code in triple-backticks ```multi_line_code()``` for better readability.

Comment: Search the Boost.GIL docs for `image_view` and `interleaved_view`